# Is there a better noun form of "unreasonable" than "unreasonableness?"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I simply can't bring myself to use *unreasonableness*, but can think of no synonym or alternate form with comparable meaning.

I'll restructure if necessary, but wonder if I'm missing a suitable alternative.

Comment: To advocate for the devil a bit: *unreasonability.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try contrariness, obduracy, or obstinacy.

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few alternatives to "unreasonableness"

- inflexibility
- immovability
- intransigence
- intractability
- stubbornness
- recalcitrance
- willfulness
- contrariness
- doggedness
- single-mindedness

Answer (score 3):

How about irrationality, or pigheadedness for that vernacular charm? Incorrigibility could also fit, as could idiocy, although I think those are deviating from "unreasonableness." Megalomania most likely doesn't work, but it's a wonderful word. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try obstinance for someone being willfully unreasonable or obtuseness if it's more a matter of their nature.

Comment: *Obstinacy* would probably get a better reaction.