# "Senseless" and "irrelevant" synonyms of "unreasonable"

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Aren't "senseless" and "irrelevant" synonyms of "unreasonable"?

This question is related to:

- [What does it mean when someone calls himself “non sequitur”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15402/what-does-it-mean-when-someone-calls-himself-non-sequitur)
- comments to to my answer to [Is there a better noun form of “unreasonable” than “unreasonableness?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9340/is-there-a-better-noun-form-of-unreasonable-than-unreasonableness/15379#15379)

Is not “unreasonable” synonym to “senseless” and “irrelevant”?

Update:
Thanks for answers. 
I still did not grasp the definitions well.

Is the behavior of [Grigori Perelman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigori_Perelman),
insistingly rejecting intrusions into his private life,
for example, like making a show of him by awarding him a $million,
is seen as non sequitur, unreasonable or senseless
in the eyes of general public and organizers of shows around mathematical sciences?

Comment: Re: the specific instance of Perelman rejecting the Clay prize. It is not a non sequitur/it is a relevant response. Rejecting a prize has an accepted history of protest. It might be reasonable, maybe he's happy without the money and the money would make his life worse, frankly, he should just accept the money and give to charity (a math research fund?). It might be senseless if he needed the money for a medical procedure. 'Senesless' could be viewed as an extreme of 'unreasonable'. But these three are not synonymous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For purposes of illustration: suppose you're having a discussion, say, about English grammar, and the other person says:

..."I know you've brought many proofs for your opinion, and I know that my way can lead to ambiguities in writing. Still, though, I insist that you are wrong." - then he's being unreasonable.

..."Argle-bargle-fargle!" - then he's being senseless.

..."Look! Ponies!" - then what he's saying is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks, but this is highly subjective. Possibly others just could not understand the point, meaning, reasons, relations with previous cobversation  of saying: ""Argle-bargle-fargle!" and "Look! Ponies". There are always reasons, rationale and meaning. For example, to stop annoying conversation or to avoid time-consuming explanations.  I'd like to receive answers to update of my question

Answer (score 2):

Those words are not synonyms.

*Unreasonable* means:

- not guided by or based on good sense
- beyond the limits of acceptability or fairness

*Senseless* means:

- (referred to a person) unconscious
- without discernible meaning or purpose

*Irrelevant* means "not connected with or relevant to something".

> Your requests are unreasonable.
>   She has been left senseless, in the middle of the street.
>   What you are saying is irrelevant; the incident would have happened even if you would have been arrived 10 minutes before.

**<sub>[Reference: the *New Oxford American Dictionary*.]</sub>**

Answer (score 0):

Those words are not related. If they all apply equally well in a situation, it still doesn't make them synonyms. They're entirely unrelated facets of the situation. They're also subjective opinion words. If someone unjustly used all three of these words to insult someone else. Does it make those words a synonym for "insult"?